# How to use JNDI datasource provided by JBoss in Spring - Wrong driver class

Tags: spring, jboss7.x

Our project has to switch from datasource configuration below to a jndi datasource provided by JBoss AS 7.1.1.

applicationContext.xml:

```
...
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="xxxx" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean   
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform"  
             value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
...
```

'old' datasource from applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="0" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300" />
</bean>
```

database.properties:

```
database.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx:xxx/
database.username=username
database.password=pwd
```

'new' datasource configuration with jndi:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" resource-ref="false">
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

server.log:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class org.h2.Driver] for 
this connection URL [jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx:xxx]
at   
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(
LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:251)
... 68 more
```

Where I have to add driverclass? JNDI call correct?